# Concatenate two values in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way to concatenate values

```
$mark = $_SESSION["mark"];  //consider this 2

$p1 = 10;
$p2 = 20;
$p3 = 30;

$price = $p.$mark;   //i want result 20  [$p2]
```

Thanks

Comment: @NabeelKhan OP doesn't have enough rep points to upvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate variable names and strings to get dynamic variable names like this:

```
$price = ${'p'.$mark};
```

The curly braces tell php to evaluate the content in them and then `$` makes it a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

A much more maintainable and usable approach to this scenario overall would be to use an array for the "p" values:

```
$mark = $_SESSION["mark"];  //consider this 2
$pVals = array(1 => 10, 2 => 20, 3 => 30);
$price = $pVals[$mark];
```